# Why is work done in compressing a gas in piston but not when a gas freely expands?

Tags: thermodynamics

According to the kinetic theorem of gases, the internal energy of an ideal gas is solely dependent on the temperature of a gas. In the free expansion of a gas, it is said that the internal energy change in the gas is zero because the temperature is constant. Let us consider a piston compressing a gas. Ultimately the result is the same, that is, the volume of both bodies is change from one state to another, yet in one there is said to be an internal energy change but not the other.

I considered a solution may be that more parameters are required to describe gas and the parameter I used was kinetic energy. However in Ideal gas expansions, there is an equation relating the kinetic energy and pressure, so one adjusts in accordance with other, so how exactly would we describe the adjustments being made in the system in accordance with the equation below?

$$ \frac{2}{3} Mv^2= PV$$

Update:

[image]

Here I argue that the energy shouldn't change even if the piston is moving because even as the gas molecules strike the moving piston pump, the momentum is still completely conserved. So the conditions of the gas being in a steady-state and piston moving are completely equivalent.

Comment: You mean 1/2 not 2/3 right? Though PV has units of energy,  Expansion or compression boundary work is $\int PdV$ not simply PV

Comment: Yes but at a particular state of the gas, isn't all of it's energy said to be in terms of kinetic according to kinetic theory of gases? That's why I wrote that

Comment: Does the piston have mass?

Comment: @Buraian So the piston is free and is accelerating due to pressure?

Comment: @ChetMiller I'm not quite sure, It was not an explicitly stated assumption in my thermodynamic book. I'll recheck it

Comment: @Umaxo I can't authoritatively answer this because I'm not very sure of the physical description of what's going on but I think that piston must be acceleration because pressures causes force?

Comment: @Buraian you claim the momentum on piston is conserved and collisions are elastic. This means, piston must be free and momentum is transferred on every collision, thus in general it should accelerate. Usually in thermodynamics, the movement of piston is fixed and momentum thus is not conserved, as something from outside must enforce the movement of piston.

Comment: Wow I just had a realization when you said that, if the piston becomes more rigid like it can move only in one way then the collisions are no longer elastic!! Awesome, could you post this as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having difficulty following your analysis. But I will offer the following comments to, hopefully, be of help.

> According to kinetic theorem of gases, the internal energy of an ideal
> gas is solely dependent on the temperature of a gas.

Correct.

> In free expansion of a gas, it is said that the internal energy change
> in the gas is zero because the temperature is constant,...

Better to say it the other way around. If the change in internal energy is zero, then for an ideal gas the change in temperature is zero, because for an ideal gas, any process, $\Delta U=mC_{V}\Delta T$.

Also, you need to say what you mean by a "free expansion". Lets assume you have a rigid, insulated cylinder partitioned in half with an ideal gas in one half and a vacuum in the other, and you put a hole in the partition. The gas will freely expand into the vacuum. Since the cylinder is rigid no boundary work is done, $W=0$, and since it is insulated no heat transfer occurs with the surroundings and $Q=0$. From the first law $\Delta U=Q-W$, so $\Delta U=0$. Finally, at the end of the free expansion the volume of the gas will have doubled and its pressure halved. Consequently, $\Delta (PV)=0$. From the ideal gas law

$$\Delta (PV)=mR\Delta T$$

Therefore,

$$\Delta T=0$$

> and let's consider a piston compressing a gas. Ultimately the result is same, that is, the volume of both bodies are change from one state to another, yet in one there is said to be an internal energy change but not the other.

It's not clear what kind of compression process you are talking about. But if the cylinder is insulated ($Q=0$), then there will be an increase in internal energy equal to the work $W$ done on the gas (assumes massless piston) when the gas is compressed back to its original volume.

On the other hand, if the the cylinder is not insulated and the compression is carried out reversibly and isothermally ($\Delta (PV)=0$), then the gas will return to its initial pressure and volume in its original side of the cylinder and $\Delta U=0$.

> so how exactly would we describe the adjustments being made in the
> system in accordance with the equation below?
>
> $$ \frac{2}{3} Mv^2= PV$$

For the free expansion of an ideal gas as I described above, you can say that

$$\Delta U=\Delta KE=\Delta (PV)$$

Where $\Delta KE$ = the change in the average translational kinetic energy of the gas particles, i.e., the change in internal energy of the ideal gas.

And since for the free expansion (an the reversible isothermal compression to return the gas to its original state) $\Delta (PV)=0$, then $\Delta KE=0$.

Or again per the ideal gas equation

$$\Delta (PV)=mR\Delta T=0$$

> Update:
>
> Here I argue that the energy shouldn't change even if piston is moving
> because even as the gas molecules strike the moving piston pump, the
> momentum is still completely conserved. So the conditions of the gas
> being in a steady state and piston moving are completely equivalent.

It's not clear what's going on in your diagram. If the cylinder is not insulated and the compression is carried out isothermally, then heat is transferring out of the gas of the same magnitude energy of the work done by the gas by the piston pump such that $\Delta (PV)=0$, then yes there will be no energy change. But if the cylinder is insulated and the compression is adiabatic ($Q$ not = 0) the internal energy will increase.

> "On the other hand, if the the cylinder is not insulated and the
> compression is carried out reversibly and isothermally (Δ(PV)=0), then
> the gas will return to its initial pressure and volume in its original
> side of the cylinder and ΔU=0." You are saying whole process would run
> in reverse from end? –

It will not run in reverse spontaneously because the free expansion I described is an irreversible process. But you can return the gas to its original state by taking away the insulation away from the cylinder and inserting a massless piston with a shaft is connected to an external force, to compress the gas reversibly and isothermally. By the way, this is a way to determine the amount of entropy generated by the original irreversible process.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "On the other hand, if the the cylinder is not insulated and the compression is carried out reversibly and isothermally (Δ(PV)=0), then the gas will return to its initial pressure and volume in its original side of the cylinder and ΔU=0."

You are saying whole process would run in reverse from end?

Comment: I'll make another comment after re-reading this tomorrow,

Comment: @Buraian I've update my answer to respond to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the confusion here comes from the need to define very carefully how you go from a constrained system to a "free expansion" system.  Suppose you start with a box full of the ideal gas ("IG"). Since the molecules only interact elastically with each other and with the box itself, you can imagine the box walls acting as mirrors. If you MagicDemon disappear the box, the molecules' paths simply continue along the original vectors rather than reflecting.  There's no energy added or removed from the system.

Now let one wall of the box be your compression piston.  You cannot compress without supplying an external force to counteract the energy of the molecules hitting that wall of the box. Momentum conservation  laws thus lead to energy being transferred to the molecules (rather like a baseball -- or cricket -- bat hitting a ball) , and the gas heats up.

#edit
By comparison, if you allow expansion only by having the molecules push the putative piston-wall outwards, then the gas temperature will decrease because energy must be used to move the wall.

Comment: So you are saying the discrepancy is only happening due to the constraint? hmm

Comment: @Buraian I'm saying you need to be very careful just how you either compress or allow free expansion.

Comment: Kindly check the edit I have made in the question

Answer (score 1):

The ideal gas law is valid only for a gas in a thermodynamic equilibrium state, or for a gas subjected to a reversible process, since a reversible process consists of a continuous sequence of thermodynamic equilibrium states.  Otherwise, it gives the wrong answer for the pressure, so you can't use it to determine the work that the gas does on the piston.  This is because an irreversible process consists of a continuous sequence of non-equilibrium states.

In an adiabatic reversible expansion, the pressure the gas exerts on the piston is greater than zero, and so the gas is able to do work of the piston.  This causes the internal energy and the temperature to decrease.

In an adiabatic irreversible expansion, the force the gas exerts on the piston (assuming a massless, frictionless piston) is zero, and so the gas is not able to do work on the piston.  So the internal energy does not change, and the temperature does not change.

Comment: That is a bit weird, because if you freeze time, then the pressure volume and temperature should be related by ideal gas law? what you said suggests to me that the gas 'loses' it's idealness based on process it's subjected to...which is strange

Comment: In an irreversible process, the pressure depends not only on the volume, but also on the rate of change of volume.  So you can't just freeze time for an irreversible process.  This may sound strange to you, but, when you study fluid mechanics, you will learn that this is exactly what happens.  The difference is in the viscous stresses that are significant in rapid deformations of a gas.

Comment: hmm could you explain how exactly a process (long term phenomena) has an effect on a short term phenomena like the applicability of gas law?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  But, if you are really serious about undersanding this, get yourself a copy of a good book on fluid mechanics such as Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, and read Chapter 1.

Comment: From what I understand, as long as you have an ideal gas, you can always apply the gas law as it is a law on the substance. But here you suggest that the law may or may not hold true depending on the process but how is that possible? Isn't PV always equal to NRT?

And, I've seen for derivation for adiabatic equation $ PV^{\gamma} = C$ and even in that derivation they use ideal gas law.

Comment: I shall check the book soon, I had been planning to start fluids for a while :D

Comment: You understand incorrectly.  The ideal gas law only applies at thermodynamic equilibrium.

Comment: Could you suggest where I could read more about this?( Does the fluids book contain this?)

Comment: Yes. Check it out.