# The pressure used in calculating workdone in Isobaric Process

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure

[image]

I tried to solve this question after reading out some good books and answer from stake exchange also. still my answer is stuck to 1 kJ. I don't clearly understand which pressure is used in calculating isobaric workdone and why.

[Work done "by gas" in a isobaric process?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/581875/)

here is the answer I read and is excellent but how do I apply it to this problem. and why the official answer to this question is 2 kJ?

This is fundamental question and I am afraid I won't be able to understand further questions if i get stuck here. so, if you can, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is ambiguous because it depends on what you call your system.  Apparently there is a mass sitting on top of the massless frictionless piston that causes the pressure of the gas to be 200 kPa higher than the external pressure of 100 kPa.  So the work done by the gas on the mass is 3 kJ, and the work done by the mass to push back the external atmosphere is 1 kJ.  So the net amount of work done to raise the mass is 2 kJ, which is considered the net useful work done by the "system."

Comment: exactly that is what i thought but the answer given is completely different and everybody has adopted the solution to match the answer. I thought my basics were wrong and I had to ask here. sorry for the trouble and thank you so much for the reply!